# Extracting Nth delimited field with the delimiter characters

Tags: regex

There are many examples how to extract the data.
In my case, I need help to extract the first and last chars of the extracted data.

For example:

```
|scooby|pluto|guffy|mickey|
```

I need to extract `guffy` with pipes, i.e, `|guffy|`

I can extract the `guffy`, but I need it with pipes included

```
^([^\|]*\|){3}(?<guffy>[^\|]*)
```

Please assist

Comment: So include them in the group: `^[^|]*(?:\|[^|]*){2}(?<guffy>\|[^|]*\|)` - see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9tQIDL/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^[^|]*(?:\|[^|]*){2}(?<guffy>\|[^|]*\|)
```

If the field can be the last one, with no `|` on the right, use

```
^[^|]*(?:\|[^|]*){2}(?<guffy>\|[^|]*\|?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9tQIDL/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^|]*` - zero or more chars other than `|`
- `(?:\|[^|]*){2}` - two occurrences of a `|`, then zero or more chars other than `|`
- `(?<guffy>\|[^|]*\|)` - Group "guffy": `|` + zero or more chars other than `|` + `|`.

The `\|?` part is an optional `|` char.